# Render an HTML snippet without saving it to a file

Tags: html, powershell

I have a PowerShell command that returns an HTML snippet:

```
(Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate -Identity Microsoft.WebSiteSQLDatabase.0.3.17-preview).description
```

[image]

Is there a way to easily render that snippet without first saving it to a file? e.g. perhaps throw it into a web browser?

Comment: You can throw a HTML to a browser, for example, save the output as `*.html` and start `iexplore` with the saved file as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Vesper. Really I was wondering if there's a way to pass it to a browser (or something else capable of rendering HTML) without first having to save to a file. I'll update the first post accordingly.

Comment: Whatever tutorials I see on this topic always save to file and implicitly call `start` on the file. Maybe this will be the best answer for your question.

Comment: How about a new answer now that MSIE is fully abandoned and unsupported.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new Internet Explorer instance and inject your HTML snippet into the body of a blank page:

```psh
$id   = 'Microsoft.WebSiteSQLDatabase.0.3.17-preview'
$html = (Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate -Identity $id).description

$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'

$ie.Navigate('about:blank')
do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
} until ($ie.ReadyState -eq 4)

$ie.Document.body.innerHTML = $html

$ie.Visible = $true
```

Comment: Hi, any requirements in terms of versions in PS or IE? This works in my computer (Win10 1903), but it doesn't on a Win2012R2 server... In fact in the server `$ie.Document | gm` doesn't give `mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass` but `System.__ComObject#{c59c6b12-f6c1-11cf-8835-00a0c911e8b2}`

Comment: Got a way to make it work: 
`If ($oIE.document.psbase.tostring() –eq “system.__comobject”) {
    $oIE.document.write([string]$proclist)
}
else {
    $oIE.document.IHTMLDOcument2_write([string]$proclist)
}` 

But still I would like to know way is this happening, thanks!

Comment: Source for that code: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/controlling-internet-explorer-object-from-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

Not without saving it to the file, but you can create 1 liner function for that:

```
function render-html { $input > out.html; start out.html; sleep 1; rm out.html }

"<b>meh</b>" | render-html
```